# Dependency Injection by constructor - Mockito tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-data

I am dealing with following problem
I created a service class that has a repository (Spring Data) as dependency, I am injecting by constructor. In this example I am using Lombok

[image: Service Class]

[image: Repository Interface]

I would like to know how can I test it with Mockito, I tried this way but it didn't work, the repository interface passed by parameter is getting null at the constructor.

I remove the Lombok to be possible to see the value getting null at the constructor.

[image: Test Class]

[image: Service Class]

If I change the dependency injection to @Autowired it works but I want to know how to test it this way.

Thank you so much
I am a beginner on that...

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, I changed my test class this way:

[image]

Source:
https://www.arhohuttunen.com/junit-5-mockito/

Answer (score 0):

You need not initialize the AuthorService class.
Also, you need to specify that the response method is a mock as well. You can do it as follows:

```
@Mock
private AuthorRepository repo;

@InjectMocks
private AuthorService authorService;

   @Test
   public void testMethod(){
   Mockito.when(authorRepository.findByNameContaining(ArgumentMatchers.any()).thenReturn(authorList);
   //your assertions goes here

   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. \n

Apparently I cannot inject mock this service because it is an interface. \n

Message error: \n

org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot instantiate InjectMocks field named 'authorService'! Cause: the type 'AuthorService' is an interface.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
Examples of correct usage of InjectMocks:
   InjectMocks Service service = new Service();
   InjectMocks Service service;
   //and... don't forget about some Mocks for injection :)

Comment: You can still inject it like this, as you already have an implementation for this class. 
Try
`@BeforeEach
 void init_mocks() {
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
 }`

Comment: Hi leorosignoli,
I found a solution, I posted the answer.
The MockitoAnnotations.initMocks is deprecated in the JUnit 5, it was replaced by MockitoAnnotations.opensMocks.

https://www.arhohuttunen.com/junit-5-mockito/

I found it thanks to your comment.

Thank you so much